# How to flash a JFrame on the Windows taskbar when it needs attention

Tags: java, notify, taskbar

I'm a computer science student working on a Yahoo! Messenger-like program implemented in Java.

My problem is that whenever the `JTextArea` inside my frame contains new message updates, the user must be prompted even when his/her frame is minimized. Is there a workaround on how to make the `JFrame` on the taskbar blink when updates are received?

In short, I need a way to notify the user that the frame has been updated even though it is minimized.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489255/using-swing-how-can-i-flash-the-windows-taskbar).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using swing how can I flash the Windows Taskbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489255/using-swing-how-can-i-flash-the-windows-taskbar)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `JFrame.toFront()`, although I don't think it is the best way to do what you want.

Comment: Focus would be lost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423987/blink-jframe-in-swing-without-transferring-focus