# Blink icon, on change

Tags: java, swing, jframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I flash the Windows taskbar using Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489255/how-can-i-flash-the-windows-taskbar-using-swing)

In most programs, the icon displayed in the taskbar will blink, if a change has been made to an iconified frame.

Like this, in "Preubas Con F...":

[image]

How could this be done, in Java?

Comment: We could use a little more information, like the UI framework being used, etc.

Comment: Do you mean the sort of orange highlight (in Windows 7)?  Last I checked, it's not possible without native code.

Comment: @vulcan correct, that is what I mean.

Comment: Alright.  I don't believe there's a specific term for that, so for clarity, you should add an image of it to the question.

Comment: @ChrisGerken Obviously you can't change the UI of a `JFrame`, since it doesn't subclass `JComponent`, so I mean the native window.

Comment: Also, [this article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/08/swing.html) covers window flashing on Windows operating systems (but it's two thirds of the way down the web page).