# How to make JFrame alert in taskbar?

Tags: java, alert, taskbar

I was wondering if Java or JFrame can alert user when something happened in the program. For example, when in Skype you receive a new message, Skype icons background changes to yellow.
[image: "You have received a new message!"]

Can I do this in Java?

Comment: what do you mean by something happened in the program.

Comment: When a certain method finished working or when an IF statement returns true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a notification in swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240415/how-to-create-a-notification-in-swing)

Comment: @Frakcool nope, they are talking about notifications in tray area, that doesn't correlate to this topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I flash the Windows taskbar using Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489255/how-can-i-flash-the-windows-taskbar-using-swing)

Comment: @VitalijKornijenko yeah you're right... sadly I can't take off my flag... let's wait until it gets rejected :)

Comment: Sadly, there's no way to do this from within Java itself, this is native concept. You will need to investigate a JNI/JNA solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least you can change the icon of the JFrame by calling [JFrame#setIconImage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29) method that looks like a notification and also change the title as well if needed.

Create a icon as you want to show when there is any notification and set the icon from the code wherever you want.

---

To create a glow (blink) effect you can use two images and swap at a interval if window in minimized form using [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and stop the timer when window is again deiconified.

Read more [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

sample code:

```
private boolean swap;
private Timer timer;

....

final Image onImage = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/1.png"))).getImage();
final Image offImage = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/2.png"))).getImage();

// interval of 500 milli-seconds
timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (swap) {
            setIconImage(onImage);
        } else {
            setIconImage(offImage);
        }
        swap = !swap;
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(true);

// check whether window is in ICONIFIED state or not
if (getExtendedState() == JFrame.ICONIFIED) {
    timer.start();
}


addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        // set the icon back to default when window is DEICONIFIED 
        timer.stop();
    }
});
```

Comment: also he could use a Timer in order to make it amm how to say it "light on and light off"? I dunno how to explain it... I mean to make it "glow"

Comment: +1 haven't tested but maybe I'll use it in my own app :)

Comment: Thanks @Braj that will be helpful since this is my only option :)

Comment: discover more if you find any one then please post an answer here.